# Is this matrix TU?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, total-unimodularity

> Is the following matrix $A$ totally unimodular?
>
> $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Recall that a matrix is totally unimodular if every square submatrix $B$ has determinant $0$, $1$ or $-1$.

It surely looks like it, since every $B$ of $1 \times 1$ surely is, $3 \times 3$ are only two options and $2 \times 2$ gives really just two cases both which satisfy the required property. Is there a faster way to conlcude this though?

Comment: The $3\times3$ submatrix you get  by deleting the 2nd column has determinant $2$, I think.

Comment: The one with column 1 and 4 missing and row 1 missing has determinant -1.

Comment: Let us add all rows to one of them, we get 2,3,2,2, oh, so if we get rid of that 3, we have 2,2,2 in our hands, the determinant built out of that columns (1st, 3rd, 4th) has to be zero to still qualify as a TU, and not be immediately disqualified, else it has a factor two. But it is not zero.

Comment: More generally, there are various criteria for testing whether or not a matrix is totally unimodular, see for example https://www.ise.ncsu.edu/fuzzy-neural/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2018/04/Lecture6.pdf